# mysqldump does not keep ON UPDATE RESTRICT

Tags: mysql

I have the following create-table-query:

```sql
`CREATE TABLE `order_meta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order_meta_key_index` (`order_id`,`meta_key`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_meta_order_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34064 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

when i run an export / mysqldump, it gives me. running `SHOW CREATE TABLE order_meta` gives me the same, so i guess thats where the problem lies.

```sql
`CREATE TABLE `order_meta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order_meta_key_index` (`order_id`,`meta_key`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_meta_order_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34064 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

notice the 'ON UPDATE RESTRICT' that has been removed. After when i delete a row from 'orders' the rows in 'order_meta' are not removed. When i remove the foreign key and re-add with the on update, it works again. Is this expected behavior or am i missing something here?

```
`alter table order_meta drop FOREIGN KEY `order_meta_order_id`;`

`alter table order_meta add CONSTRAINT `order_meta_order_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;`
```

Comment: What version of server and mysqldump are you using?

Comment: Adding or not adding `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` has the same effect, as it is the default action anyway. Also, whatever you define in `ON UPDATE` has no effect on deleting a row from `orders`, as it would only have an effect on updates. Please check your value for `SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` when the effect *"After when i delete a row from 'orders' the rows in 'order_meta' are not removed."* happens (it should be 1. If it is 0, foreign keys do not work, most likely as an option during import).

Comment: @Solarflare Indeed, thats exactly what i thought, but somehow it's strange that when adding the `ON UPDATE` fixes the problem of the related records not being deleted, even though `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` should be the default value. The value for FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is also 1 (enabled). The import disabled and re-enables this.

Comment: @ysth i was using workbench 8.0.13, i upgraded to 8.0.19 and that seems to have fixed the issue. The export now contains the `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` and the `CONSTRAINTS` keep working after a re-import. Still weird how it didn't work, see my comment @Solarflar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this had to do with outdated workbench to create the mysqldump.